# How to turn on FSAA on Mac? (27" iMac i5)

Tags: macos, anti-aliasing

I'm playing StarCraft2 
there's no option to turn on FSAA in the game. As you know, there is no way to set FSAA in Mac OS X. How can I turn this feature on?

My Mac is 27" iMac i5 with ATI Radeon HD 4850.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with FSAA of StarCraft II on ATI cards. A hotfix was released, but appears to be Windows-only at this time. Bummer. http://www.crunchgear.com/2010/07/30/ati-releases-starcraft-ii-anti-aliasing-hotfix/